# Security of Custom Distribution

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have configured a Jessie-lite distribution for Raspberry Pi Zero with everything just right. I would like to distribute the entire SD card image to Ham Radio operators to simplify things for them.
I'm wondering what steps I should take to not give up any secrets before I make the image public? This is all I could think of:

- remove wifi password
- rm ssh known hosts file
- default password is standard "raspberry"

Anything else?
Is this even a good idea?

Thanks

Bob